# How to set a image path in yii framework?

Tags: html, yii, yii2

Here is my coad.

```
<?=Html::img('file_path',['alt' => 'class room'])?>
```

my image real path is `web/image/class.jpg`. How to set the path in file_path.

Anybody knows how to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;

```
<?=Html::img( Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;  .  'file_path',['alt' => 'class room'])?>
```

could be you need /image/

```
<?=Html::img(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;  . '/image/' .  'file_path',['alt' => 'class room'])?>
```

see  this for more http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-url.html

You can try  with @web to ... but  instead of 'file_path' .. you probably need a $model->attribute refer

```
<?= Html::img('@web/image/' . $model->file_path , ['alt' => 'class room']) ?>
```

Comment: <?=Html::img( Url::home(true) .'/image/'.  'web/images/class.jpg',['alt' => 'class room'])?>       is this correct??

Comment: plz tell me the reason.

Comment: Tell me the exact cont of the field  'file_path' and the exact location in you dir  .. so i  can confirm your code in comment .. eventaully try var_dump(Html::img( Url::home(true) .'/image/'. 'web/images/class.jpg') and adjust the code .

Comment: my project is a SRS. My image dir is web/images/class.jpg.

Comment: and the content of the field 'file_path'  is the image filename only?

Comment: @C.Roshan   try the new answer  and let me know .

Comment: I have update the answer .. but  .. what the content of  'file_path' could be you need to related at $model->file_path ..

Comment: Thanks in advance. its works. Sorry for waste ur time. And Thank you....

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<img src="<?=Yii::$app->request->baseUrl?>/image/class.jpg">
```

**Yii::$app->request->baseUrl :** It returns path from root to web

OR you can use

```
<img src="<?=Yii::getAlias('@web'); ?>/image/class.jpg">
```

Comment: thank you for response me.But not work. I'm beginner for the yii.

Comment: Nothing. I mean other text and buttons are shows. But not a image.